# Path to XML dosent work

Tags: c#, xml

Everytime i try to save something to my created XML document the path i use keeps being wrong.
Here is the code:

```
public string ToXml<T>(T obj, string path)
    {

        var saveToXmlPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location), path);
        using (var stringWriter = new StreamWriter((saveToXmlPath)))
        {
            var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ObservableCollection<object>));
            xmlSerializer.Serialize(stringWriter, obj);
            return stringWriter.ToString();
        }

    }

    public Constructor()
    {
        var temp = new ObservableCollection<Model> {
             new Model { ID = 1, Name = "Name1" },
             new Model { ID = 2,  Name = "Name2" },
             new Model { ID = 3,  Name = "Name3" } };
        ToXml(temp, @"Common\Assets\XML\XmlFile.xml");

    }
```

It keep saying that the path is wrong, keeps adding /debug/big to the path.

Comment: what's the value of Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location ?

Comment: Based on your comment in another answer, the path the assembly is returning is `C:\\Users\\UserName\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2015\\Projects\\SolutionName\\ProjectName\\bin\\Debug\\ ` which is correct.  When visual studio compiles your application it will place it in the `bin` directory, and then inside a subdirectory for the configuration, in this case `debug`.  that is the location that the actual compiled .exe is running from.  Where do you EXPECT it to try and write the file?

Comment: I expect it to write the file to the location i've created the xml document.

Comment: I know very little of xml so plz tell me of how it should work, if i say to the program exactly where the xml document is, shouldnt it write there?

Answer (score 0):

Set a breakpoint on this line:

```
var saveToXmlPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location), path);
```

What does it say?

Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location is adding /debug to your path.

Comment: this limits the directory structure of where the page is deployed.  not the best...

Comment: It says : "C:\\Users\\UserName\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2015\\Projects\\SolutionName\\ProjectName\\bin\\Debug\\Common/Assets/XML/XmlFile.xml"

Comment: Get the same thing with big\\debug when i use 
 AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory +  @"ThePath/XmlFile.xml"

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your "problem" has nothing to do with **XML**. You're wanting to know why `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location` is giving you ".../bin/Debug".

Secondly... from what little information you have actually provided, there is in fact no problem at all; just your misunderstanding. `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location` will give you the location of the executing "**.exe**" file (your app). In this case, that would indeed be inside the "bin/Debug" folder by default. If you want the XML file written somewhere else, then it would be helpful if you would specify where you think that somewhere else should be.